# swift - Proper way to place UITextView with button below UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I'm very new to Xcode so please excuse my ignorance. I'm creating a view controller that contains a table view, a text view, and a button. The table view rows will contain comments from users. I want to place a text view and button at the bottom of the screen so users can enter a comment on the thread. What would be the best way to situate a text view and button at the bottom of the screen while allowing the rows in the table view to be scrolled?

Comment: show what you have done here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, table views support scrolling. You could pretty much place the textView and button on top of the tableView; In the user's perspective, it's a reasonable compromise... although Apple's HCI guidelines will reprimand you for that.

The proper way is to use UIInsets to adjust the tableView to allow for the text view and button on the bottom of the screen. That is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but I tripped up on this thread looking for something else. This is typically handled with an input accessory view and UIToolbar. Starting your search from there will make sense.